# Import SQL from excel and run in Python

Tags: python, sql, excel, oracle

Hopefully someone can help me with this !! I am using cx_Oracle for oracle DB connection, I want to store a few SQL queries in excel. by running script in python, the sql can be imported from excel can be executed.

The sql1 has successfully import the sql1 but the value cannot pass to c.execute. How can I make it right? Adding """ will not help.

```
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('C:\\Python\Excel\sql.xlsx', sheet_name='SQL1')
caseno = excel_data_df['Case no']
sql1 = excel_data_df['SQL']
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql1)*
```

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: where is your connection?

Comment: What do you mean "but the value cannot pass to c.execute."?  Are you getting an error?  Can you give the exact text of a statement that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for everyone ! this comes with error because i am passing a list of records to sql and the conn.cursor cannot run multiple sql at one time.